# Template string being written as literal in Mirth transformer mapping?

Tags: mirth

Template string being written as literal in Mirth (v3.10) transformer mapping?
I am trying to fill the HL7 (v2.3) [MSH.7](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.3/Fields/MSH.7) (date/time) field in a message from a Mirth Source Transformer by mapping the MSH[7] field to the javascript one-liner

```js
`${new Date().getFullYear()}` + `${new Date().getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getDate()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getHours()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getSeconds()}`.padStart(2, "0")
```

[image]
(to get datetime as format YYYMMDDHHMMSS) but when looking at the result (in the resulting file that gets written at the Channel's Destination) **I see the literal code** as text rather than what it should evaluate to (even though it is my understanding that Mirth [does support](https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/18349-javascript-es6-overview) string templates now). The step successfully validates in the editor and errors out when I make the string wrong in a JS context, so I assume that (at least at that stage) it *is being interpreted as JS code*.

Have also tried

```js
(`${new Date().getFullYear()}` + `${new Date().getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getDate()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getHours()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getSeconds()}`.padStart(2, "0")).toString()
```

so in the Generated Code tab, I see

```js
tmp['MSH'][i]['MSH.7']['MSH.7.1'] = validate('', `${new Date().getFullYear()}` + `${new Date().getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getDate()+1}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getHours()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, "0") + `${new Date().getSeconds()}`.padStart(2, "0")).toString(), new Array());
```

but got similar results (even though both work as expected when just testing on the Node CLI interpreter).

Anyone with more experience know what could be going on here? (PS. is there an easier way to get the datetime into that field)?

Comment: In that forum post you linked, I explained why template strings are still not supported. Mirth's javasript engine is Mozilla Rhino, and they are still not supported in Rhino. There are links at the bottom of the mirth forum post to Rhino issues that are still open regarding template strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla Rhino is the javascript engine used by (Mirth) Connect. Template literals are still unsupported at this time. See below for a listing of which features are present and missing in mirth. Check the server-lib directory in your mirth install directory and look for the rhino jar to see which version is packaged with your version of mirth. Only mirth versions 3.7 and higher allow you to set the language version required to enable some of the features. Older versions run at a language version of zero or "default".

https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html#ES2015-syntax-template-literals

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround (why Mirth cannot use JS template strings still unknown)

---

Still do not know why the template string is not working, but after playing with the Reference tab a bit and looking around the [community forums](https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/17275-converting-current-date-time-to-datetime-format-for-sql-server-14) found a *workaround* by dragging the Get Current Date reference into the Mapping field and specifying the desired format pattern as shown below.

[image]

After doing this and redeploying the channel, I see the date formatted in the way I was trying to do (**though if anyone can explain why the template string evaluates to the literal code I'd mark that as the accepted answer because I still have seen no answer for why they don't actually work**).